# Visual Basic try catch duplicate key not caught

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlexception

I'm having a problem with error handling. Via a VB program, I want to add a duplicate key to a SQL Server 2008 R2 table. I'm using the following code:

```
Public Shared Function AddCatPlanilla(ByVal CatPlanilla As CatPlanilla) As Boolean
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = EnterpriseDB.GetConnection
    Dim insertStatement As String _ = "INSERT [dbo].[CatPlanilla] " _
        & "([CodEmpr], [TipoCatalogo], [CodAsoc], [Descripcion], [DescripcionCorta]) " _
        & "VALUES (@CodEmpr, @TipoCatalogo, @CodAsoc, @Descripcion, @DescripcionCorta)"
    Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection)
    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodEmpr", CatPlanilla.m_CodEmpr)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoCatalogo", CatPlanilla.m_TipoCatalogo)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodAsoc", CatPlanilla.m_CodAsoc)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", CatPlanilla.m_Descripcion)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionCorta", CatPlanilla.m_DescripcionCorta)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

When I want to add a duplicate key, sqlexception doesn't catch the error and the following information is displayed on the screen (stopping the program):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred

Class=14

ErrorCode=-2146232060

HResult=-2146232060

LineNumber=1

Message=Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CatPlanilla' with unique index
'IX_CatPlanilla'. The duplicate key value is (001, LT, Lima).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't know what's causing this or whether it's a problem with SQL server configuration or Visual studio configuration.

I want to emphasize that the program never jumps to the CATCH section. The program stops at the line that says "Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery ()"
What a shame That I can not send the picture, sorry

Comment: You are throwing the exception - what do you want to happen when you are trying to a duplicate key?

Comment: I want that the program go to the catch section but no, the program stopped in the line says "Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in these lines of code

```
Catch ex As SqlException
    Throw ex
```

This block of code will catch the exception and then immediately rethrow it.  It essentially means the code has no effect on your program other than to reset the stack trace.  If you actually want to catch the program and prevent it from crashing then you need to remove the `Throw ex` line.  Instead try showing a message

```
Catch ex As SqlException
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Jaredpar. My problem is that the program sopped in the line says "Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()" pointing to Executenonquery. (What a shame that I can not send the picture, sorry). Never jump to the catch section.

Comment: @user2705541 why not move that code into the body of the `try` block as well?